# Lotus Notes ODBC Connection

Tags: sql, sql-server, odbc, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I need to connect and send/receive information from an MS SQL server in my Lotus Notes app using @formula in realtime (I can connect using an agent, but I need to use inline code for this).

The commands themselves seem pretty straight forward, but setting up the configurations seems to be a topic with scarce documentation. Apparently I need to install an ODBC driver. Where would I find that, and do I install that onto the server or onto the workstations that will run this app?

If any Lotus gurus could step me through setting this up, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to install the ODBC driver on the workstations that run this app, if the users will be triggering the ODBC connections.  If at all possible, I highly suggest setting this up on the server side, and having it run via an agent.  That'll save you from a few headaches, including having to maintain the ODBC connections on each workstation and worrying if each workstation has access to the data and server.

You first just want to make sure your ODBC setup is correct.  You'll need the appropriate driver, of course, and the connection information.  This site has a walkthrough to give you an idea of [how to setup an ODBC database connection](http://www.ehow.com/how_4642566_setup-odbc-database-connection.html)

If you have MS Access you can use it to test querying from the ODBC data source.  Once you've tested the connection works, you'll just refer to the data source name (DSN) in your @DbColumn, @DbLookup, or @DbCommand formulas.

Back to my suggestion on setting this up on the server side, that would mean you'd keep a copy of the data you're querying within the Notes database itself, and then users would be interacting with read-only data in Notes.  You could schedule updates regularly on the server side of that read-only data and effectively create a cache of the data in your Notes environment.  Then that data would replicate around to other replicas of the database, but remove the trouble of the ODBC connection being needed everywhere.

If you *need* realtime data, though, that solution is out the window and you'll have to go with a local solution.  In that case, you might want to look at the LCConnection class or using an ADODB.Connection from script, as both will allow you to create DSN-less connections to data sources.  You'd then save the trouble of requiring ODBC data sources on each workstation, and only have to worry about whether they can access the server from their workstation.

Comment: Please notice: if you are running Lotus Domino 32-bit on a Windows Server x64 (64-bit) then you need to define your ODBC data sources in the 32-bit ODBC Administrator program - and not in the standard 64-bit ODBC Administrator program. This is because the Lotus Domino ODBC drivers are 32-bit.

The 32-bit ODBC Administrator program is located at C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ODBCAD32.exe.

Answer (score 2):

I would add another option to Ken's list. It involves having the server do the queries of the external database (therefore you are only setting up ODBC in on the server - you don't have to deal with it on the workstations). You create an agent that is launched on the server using the 'run on server' technique. When the workstation needs to query the external data, the code creates a throw-away document in the database, puts the query criteria into the temporary document, saves the document, then calls the 'run on server' agent passing a reference to the temporary document. The server launches the agent, reads the criteria from the temporary document, does the query, and writes the results back to the temporary document. Then the workstation can access the query results from the temporary document. A scheduled agent can delete the temp docs on a regular basis.

It sounds complicated, and it all has to be done in script, but I've done this in many applications and it is fast, flexible, easy to administer, and gives your applications a lot of power. Note that end users must have the ACL rights to create a document in the db (the temp doc) in order for this to work.

Good luck!

Comment: If the user initiates this process, wouldn't the dblookup already occur by the time the agent is done retrieving and delivering the results? 

Do you add a delay to insure the information is written before the workstation performs the lookup?